# Can Redis dump the keys when it is evicted to free memory or it is expired

Tags: redis

I want to use Redis in this way

1. Load the entries (which are reading/editing by user)  from file db,
   set to expire in a period of time
2. Edit & read them on Redis
3. Store back to file db when it is auto-deleted by Redis (while it is
       evicted to free memory or it is expired  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something that Redis does OOTB but with a little effort you can achieve it. See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25827681/3160475

Comment: Thanks, that looks working, but keeping a sorted set seems taking too much memory. Still looking for any way to do it while Redis expire a key or evicted to free memory

Comment: If you have hacking skillz and are willing to fork and maintain, that's always an option with open source. In that case, I recommend that you look into "hacking" the existing Keyspace Notifications mechanism (http://redis.io/topics/notifications) for your purposes. You may find Matt's answer helpful in that context as well: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1876